# Django filter by datetime, after converting string to datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I'm trying to filter my query by a datetime. This datetime is the datetime for the value range the customer wants to know information for. I'm trying to set it to the first of the month selected by the customer. I pass the month number convert it to the correct string format and then convert to a datetime object because simply looking for the string object was returning no values and Django's documentation says you need to do it like:

```
pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 30)
```

Code:

```
if 'billing-report' in request.POST:
         customer_id = int(post_data['selected_customer'])
```

This is the code I use to get the selected customer date and turn it into a tupple

```
  if 'billing-report' in request.POST:
     customer_id = int(post_data['selected_customer'])
     selected_date = int(post_data['month'])
     if selected_date < 10:
        selected_date =  '0'+str(selected_date)
     year = datetime.now()
     year = year.year
     query_date =  str(year) + '-' + str(selected_date) +  '-01'

     query_date_filter = datetime.strptime(query_date, "%Y-%m-%d")


     compute_usages = ComputeUsages.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).filter(values_date = query_date_filter)


django debug shows: datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0)
query_date looks like: 2014-07-01  before it is converted
```

.

No error but no data is returned

I used to use:

```
compute_usages = ComputeUsages.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).filter(values_date = datetime(query_date_filter))
```

which was causing the error. I'm sorry for changing my question as it evolved that is why I'm re-including what I was doing before so the comments make sense.

Comment: `datetime(..)` is not a tuple e.g., `len()` won't work; it is an instance of `datetime` class such as returned by `datetime.strptime()` class method. Trying to pass `datetime` instance into `datetime()` would yield the "invalid integer" error: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)`

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian I was just trying it that way because passing it the other way doesn't work. I reverted back to my original way. However no data is still returned.

Comment: there could be *multiple* issues. Fixing one, does not necessarily fix all of them. Don't change your question in a such way that existing answers such as provided by @Daniel Roseman are no longer make sense.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry, I just wanted to update it to the most accurate. I appologize

Comment: BTW, you don't need to convert integers to strings, only to convert them to datetime; you could pass integers directly: `datetime(year, month, day)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after spending sometime exploring setting the query filter to datetime(year, month, day) I came to the realization that django doesn't convert it to a neutral datetime format it has to match exactly. Also my data in the database had the year, day, month.

Learning point:

You have to use the datetime() exactly how it is in the database django does not convert to a neutral format and compare. I assumed it was like writing a query and saying to_date or to_timestamp where the db will take your format and convert it to a neutral format to compare against the rest of the db.

Here is the correct way

```
 compute_usages = ComputeUsages.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).filter(values_date = datetime(year, day, selected_month))
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of that code is irrelevant to your question.

I don't understand why you are calling `datetime` on `query_date`. That is *already* a datetime, as you know because you converted it to one with `strptime` earlier. So there's no need for any more conversion:

```
ComputeUsages.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id).filter(values_date=query_date)
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways, but the other way nothing is returned. However If I take off the datetime filter it returns all the values, and if I look in the db the values for the datetime im searching for exist.